# I have three tables which contains Parent,Child,Mark. I want to merge three tables using join with union query

Tags: sql-server, join, union

In **parent** table:

```
Id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
Firstname varchar(50),
Email varchar(50)
```

In **child** table:

```
Mid int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
Mark1 int,
Mark2 int,
Id int not null foreign key references Parent(Id)
```

In **mark** table:

```
Uid int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
Mark3 int,
Id int not null foreign key references Parent(Id)
```

### My union queries are:

```
select Id,Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Parent
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Child 
union
select Null as Id,Null as Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Mark3 from Mark
```

### I have tried union with inner join query like this:

```
select * from (select Parent.Id,Parent.Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2 from Parent
union all
select Id,Null as Firstname, Mark1,Mark2 from Child) t1 inner join Mark t2 on t2.Id=t1.Id
```

But couldn't get it.

So I want the end result should be like this based on when user gives Id.

For ex:

```
Id Firstname Mark1 Mark2 Mark3
-- --------- ----- ----- -----
2   john      89    70    60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UPDATE based on comment 
>   is it possible to merge three tables without using join query which means can we use union query instead?

```
select 
  Id,
  MAX(Firstname) Firstname,
  MAX(Mark1) Mark1,
  MAX(Mark2) Mark2,
  MAX(Mark3) Mark3
from
(
select Id,Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Parent
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Child 
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Mark3 from Mark
) t
  group by id
```

Perhaps you need JOINs

```
select 
p.*, c.Mark1,c.Mark2,m.Mark3
from parent p 
  left join child c
   on p.id=c.id
  left join marks m
   on m.id=p.id
--where p.id=@userprovidedId
```

Note that this will provide multiple rows when there are more than one rows in Child or Marks table for same parentid

Comment: Thanks for your help dhruvJoshi and it works fine. is it possible to merge three tables without using join query which means can we use union query instead?

Comment: it works fine but I want the results to be like:
Id Firstname Mark1 Mark2 Mark3
--- ------------- -------- --------  --------
1  John          60        50        80

Comment: @Sridhar i don't get it.. Can you paste the output format somewhere in your question? or as an image on imgur?

Comment: @Sridhar Isn't this what you get when you run the UNION group by query I provided?

Comment: Yeah. When i run your query,I'm getting this result.
http://imgur.com/a/oilMa

But i want result to be like this
http://imgur.com/a/yjocY

is to possible to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Updating my query nevertheless.Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select 
p.*, Mark1,Mark2,m.Mark3
from parent p 
 join child c
   on p.id=c.id
  join marks m
   on m.id=p.id
```